# install multiple versions of golang

Tags: linux, go, installation, ubuntu-20.04, goland

I want to install 2 versions of go on my system(ubuntu20.04)
go 1.19 is installed globally and go 1.16 I want to install locally to a folder or globally with a mechanism of switching versions.
I have installed go version go1.19.6 linux/amd64
For installing go 1.16 linux I am following [this](https://go.dev/doc/manage-install#installing-multiple)
I have already installed go globally and it is working fine. I have also installed git.

on running command
`go install golang.org/dl/go1.16@latest`
It works fine But when I entered command  `go1.16 download` It shows `go1.16: command not found`

[Here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/37428), People are discussing about some path but I didn't get it. Can anyone please explain.

I am new to linux. I can see a file go1.16 at /home/bipl0276/go/bin. I tried running it but nothing happened

Comment: "I want to install 2 versions of go on my system" probably not. If this is for comparing (e.g. speed of the compiler) you are on the right track: `go install` installs to GOBIN (which has complicated fallback defaults if unset). If you did not botch up your installation of Go 1.19 go1.16 should be located at $HOME/bin/go1.16. Execute it via the full path. Note that this is a 100% duplicate and has _nothing_ to do with "two versions of Go" but _only_ with where `go install` puts the generated binary. (run go install with `-x` flag to see whats going on.)

Comment: I want to install it like we install multiple versions of node via nvm.

Comment: Also, they have provided documentation for Installing multiple Go versions. But I am facing some error in the same

Comment: Use case behind  installing 2 versions is to work on two different projects simultaneously which supports on different versions of go

Comment: Ensure that the directory used by `go install` is listed in your path.  https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies. Then, follow directions at https://go.dev/doc/manage-install

Comment: @ShubhamGarg since go is backwards compatible you can use 1.19 for both projects without any problems (unless there was a breaking change to fix a security issue which is uncommon) also not that since go 1.20 was released 1.16 is no longer supported and thus not getting bug fixes.

Comment: Okay: Stop that "different versions of Go like nvm"-business now: You can compile any (non-buggy) Go 1.16 project without any problem with Go 1.20. Go is _different_ than NodeJS. Install Go 1.20 and just be happy.

Comment: You can use gvm to switch and download between Go versions. Here is the solution:https://github.com/moovweb/gvm#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, I am trying to give you another perspective of solution.**

Suppose that you have go 1.19 globally installed, then install go 1.16 through tarball **rather than go install**:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.16.linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar -zxvf go1.16.linux-amd64.tar.gz -C /path/you/like/
export GOPATH=~/path-you-like/go
export GOROOT=~/path-you-like/go
# There is no need to export to PATH as we will manage go by update-alternatives
```

Use `update-alternatives` to manage multiple versions of go:

```
# Note that the /usr/bin/go is a universal executable path for go. When you config go version through update-alternatives --config go, /usr/bin/go will automatically change to the related version. 
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/go go /path/to/go-1.19/bin/go 19
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/go go /path/to/go-1.16/bin/go 16
# 19 and 16 are priorities of go-1.19 and go-1.16 respectively.
# The greater the higher priority.
```

Now you can switch and use multiple versions of go.

Answer (score 0):

If go1.16 is successfully downloaded but you can't run it directly, try checking whether you've added go/bin directory on your $PATH directory by running

> echo $PATH | grep "go/bin"

to see if you've already added go/bin to your $PATH environment variable. If you haven't, you can do so by adding

> `PATH=$PATH:/home/bipl0276/go/bin` in your shell profile e.g `~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile`.